# Returning a char array instead of const char *

Tags: c++

How to return a local char array from a function which has the return type as `const char*`?
 
***Note:*** I want a way without using std::string

```
const char * getXXX()
{
  char buf[32];
  sprintf(buf,"XXX%d",i);  // some manipulation
  return buf; // How to return???
}
```

Comment: @Spook , if I use "new" key word inside the function, where should I delete that pointer?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on *why* you don't want to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)? Using the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) will make your life as a C++ programmer so much easier!

Comment: @Nadaraj I've already answered that :) If you allocate memory inside your function, the caller is then responsible for freeing it. Unless, of course, you use `std::string` - then you can simply return it by value and don't have to worry about freeing allocated memory.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg .. since i'm using a lot of sprintf statements inside the function, i need a char buf. So, i was looking a solution without assigning the char buf again to a temp string to return the value.

Comment: You do know about [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)? Using it you can use all the normal C++ stream output formatting functionality, and still get a `std::string` as output. No fixed-size buffers, no special case handling for strings, type safety, automatic appending to the string. All of those things you can't get by using old C-style `sprintf` and family.

Comment: @Nadaraj, the correct solution to this situation is to remove the code using sprintf (see Joachim's comment), not to start working with raw char pointers - unless real-world scenario (a.k.a. "project deadline") prevents you from doing so.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thanks man for your kind help. Also thanks to Spook, shivakumar and utnapistim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const char * getXXX()
{
  static char buf[32];
  sprintf(buf,"XXX%d",i);
  return buf;
}
```

This will work

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly noticed, you should not return buf (this is a local variable and its memory will be freed after the function returns). The solution is to allocate some memory and return it.

```
char * returnBuf = new char[32];

memcpy(returnBuf, buf, 32 * sizeof(char));

return returnBuf;
```

Remember though, that the caller will be responsible for freeing memory returned by getXXX:

```
char * result = GetXXX();

// Process

delete[] result;
```